# How to avoid unsafePerformIO in the Handler Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, yesod

I have problems wrapping my head around avoiding an unsafePerformIO in a Yesod Handler. The code in the Handler is living in the Handler Monad, so how can I execute the IO operation?

```
getProfileR :: Handler Html
getProfileR = do

  -- toTMDBMovie's return-type is IO Movie
  -- Without the unsafePerformIO the type of result would be IO [Movie]
  -- How do I get from IO [Movie] to [Movie]?
  -- Ignore reccMovies - it's just a parameter.

  let result = unsafePerformIO $ mapM toTMDBMovie reccMovies

  defaultLayout $ do
      setTitle "Profile"
      $(widgetFile "profile")
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Handler` is a [`MonadIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html), so you can `result <- liftIO $ mapM toTMDBMovie reccMovies`

Comment: This is related to [monad transformers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) if you want to learn more.

Comment: @luqui Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. If you post this as an Answer, I'll mark it as correct. :)

Comment: The point here is realizing that you don't need to turn `IO [Movie]` to `[Movie]`, which is impossible to do safely, but to `Handler [Movie]`, which is done by `liftIO`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a monad `m` you are working in is of `MonadIO` class, you can use `liftIO :: IO a -> m a` to perform IO actions inside.

As for Yesod, you can perform IO action in its `Handler` actions, as well as Persistent's `runDB` blocks.